# SpringMVC serves view without controller

Tags: spring-mvc, view, tiles

I've a jspx file (for example test.jspx) in folder WEB-INF/templates and i want to access it by javascript.

I haven't a controller that returns that view, and in my application I'm using TilesViewResolver.

In test.jspx i want to use spring taglib to access message-bundle.

How i can configure spring to serve test.jspx ?

I'm using:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/templates/test.html" view-name="test" />
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/templates/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jspx</value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>
```

It doesn't works.

Comment: I've created a new ViewResolver with order=2 and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible without any controller, but you can use a controller already provided by Spring MVC: [`ParameterizableViewController`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/ParameterizableViewController.html). Just provide the name of your jsp as the viewName property.